# Make Buttons clickable once in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm Trying To make A button Only clickable once in Vb 
I was thinking of this code

```
 Sub B64_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles B64.Click
    Dim BClick As Integer = 0
    If BClick = 0 Then
        BClick = 1
        'Other instructions
    End If
```

Any Other Ideas!
    Also Can I do something so that the button will make a sound when it is clicked ?!

Any Other Ideas!
Thank u

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975569/button-disable-and-enable

Comment: BClick would have to be declared outside that code block.

Comment: For your code to run properely you have to define BClick as static `Static BClick As Integer = 0`. Static variables "remember" there last value even after leaving their scope

Comment: As for the sound part you have the standard Beep() built-in function to alert the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your click event you can do:

```
B64.Enabled = False
```

You can also play a .WAV file on click:

```
Dim player As New System.Media.SoundPlayer()
player.SoundLocation = path
player.Load()
player.Play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Disable Button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    'Do Stuff....
    '& Enable it if you want
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

you can disable button or any control with this code
by using `Button1_Click(Button1, Nothing)` or `Button1_Click(Button2, Nothing)`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Element As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Element.Enabled = False
    'Do Stuff....
    'if you want delay use: Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Element.Enabled = True
End Sub
```